# Как организовать передачу параметров через DTO?

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования, проектирование, ddd, dto

Теоретическая задача. Допустим есть сервис Article. Есть DTO для передачи параметров, дабы не использовать массив:

```
ArticleDTO{
    public $title,$text,$published;
}
```

Есть метод сервиса:

```
ArticleService::updateById($id, AtricleDTO $articelDTO ){
    $data = [];
    $data['title'] = $articelDTO->title;
    $data['text'] = $articelDTO->text;
    $data['published'] = $articelDTO->published;
    $this->repository->update($id, $data);
}
```

Ну или по феншую с entity. Не суть вопроса.

```
ArticleService::updateById($id, AtricleDTO $articelDTO ){
        $article  =  $this->repository->find($id);

        $article->setTitle($articelDTO->getTitle());
        $article->setText($articelDTO->getText());
        $article->setPublished($articelDTO->getPublished());

        $this->repository->save($article);
    }
```

Есть метод в контроллере, где нужно поменять только published. Реквестом приходит только published. А есть метод где нужно обновить всю статью.

```
 ArticleController{
        public function setPublished($id, $request){
            $articleDTO = new ArticleDTO();
            $articleDTO->published = $request->input('published');

            ArticleService::updateById($id, AtricleDTO $articelDTO );
        }
        public function store($id, $request){
            $articleDTO = new ArticleDTO();
            $articleDTO->published = $request->input('published');
            $articleDTO->title = $request->input('title');
            $articleDTO->text = $request->input('text');

            ArticleService::updateById($id, AtricleDTO $articelDTO );
        }
    }
```

Возникает проблема: $title,$text при setPublished()- будут в пустые в DTO и следовательно при обновлении они станут равны NULL. Т.е. сервис внутри не понимает разницы: свойства у DTO = NULL при установке и надо их обновить, или они не были установлены вообще и не нужно из трогать.

1. Да есть вариант создать новый метод в сервисе и в нем извлекать ровно те  свойства DTO которые нужны. Но тогда выходит 100500 методов на
   каждый чих обновления.Даже в нашем варианте, можно сделать 3 и более сценариев обновления: обновить всю статью, обновить только паблишед, обновить текст и тайтл.  И вместо одного метода update уже будут updateFull, setPublished, updateTitleAndText. Где это нужно? Банально: админ обновляет всю статью, админ может устанавливать паблишед в списке статьей в быстром режиме, пользователь может обновлять только Заголовок и Текст без изменения статуса публикации.
2. Можно передавать массив. Но это уход от ООП, никак нельзя
   контролировать передаваемые данные и прописывать их в интерфейсах.
3. Прописать в DTO функционал, который через __call высчитывает
   какие свойства были установлены, а какие нет - но это какой то
   костыль
4. Ваш вариант

Comment: Даже если вы изменяете одно поле, то скорее всего показываете админу все поля, и при отправке данных на сервер тоже можете отправлять все поля. Это позволит иметь один метод, полного обновления объекта.

Comment: Передача массива не противоречит [ООП](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/31/AttheBoundaries,ApplicationsareNotObject-Oriented/)

Answer (score 0):

А как реализован Ваш сервис? На мой взгляд сервис не должен так строго декларировать какие данные он должен поместить в базу (исключением могут быть поля created_at и updated_at, которые он может сформировать сам). Если вам необходимо проверить корректность данных на входе - это ответственность валидатора, если подать данные в нужной для сервиса форме - ответственность DataMapper'а. Я бы сделал сервис максимально простым, он просто принимает данные в примитивном виде (или принимает интерфейс, который преобразует данные для сервису в нужный ему вид), и отправляет их в базу (или еще куда-нибудь).
Создайте маппер с нужными методами, передавайте его в сервис. Пусть маппер реализует интерфейс с методом getData, который будет возвращать сервису нужные данные.

Comment: Он делает ровно то, что вы написали. А именно: "принимает интерфейс, который преобразует данные для сервису в нужный ему вид" только в виде DTO. Метод сервиса не понимает, данные которые в NULL установлены в NULL или просто не установлены.
Допишу сейчас метод сервиса